# Test recursive sed search and replace before running

Tags: sed

Is there any way to run a trial recursive search and replace using `sed`, before actually running it?  I just want to print out the results before actually doing the search and replace.  Something like echoing the results of,

```
grep -rl term1 . |xargs sed -i -e 's/term1/term2/'
```

Comment: Make a copy of the data, run your command, inspect the result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could run `sed` without `-i` and step through output with `less`

```
grep -rl --null term1 . | xargs -0 sed -e 's/term1/term2/' | less
```

Then run `sed` with `-i.bak` to create backups which you can diff afterwards

```
grep -rl --null term1 . | xargs -0 sed -i.bak -e 's/term1/term2/'
diff somefile.bak somefile
# verify changes were correct
```

*Edit:* As suggested in comment, use `grep --null | xargs -0`. This causes filenames to be terminated by the null-byte, which makes it safe for filenames with unusual characters like newline. Yes, `\n` is a valid character in a unix filename. The only forbidden characters are [slash `/` and the nul character `\0`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_169)

Comment: Interesting, I tried finding the meaning of -i but it wasn't listed under man sed.  Your solution worked.  What would be the best way in your opinion to just list the lines, not the entire file?  Instead of piping into less I piped | grep term2, which sort of worked but I got some output with strange characters as well.

Comment: @user251482 - "Just list the lines", as in "viewing a diff between the old and new file"?

Comment: Better with `grep -rlZ term1 . | xargs -r0 sed -i.bak -e s/term1/term2/`

Comment: @StephaneChazelas  Yes, or even better `grep -rl --null` since OP did not specify OS, and `-Z` means something different on BSD/OSX (decompress). `--null` is the same on both GNU and BSD

Comment: @grebneke. Good point, but note that the OP is using the GNU sed syntax, so we can assume he's not on BSDs. Note that `grep` is (a fork of) the GNU grep on FreeBSD and NetBSD. On NetBSD, `-Z` still means `--null` (according to the man page), but I agree --null is more portable. Also note that neither --null nor -Z work on OpenBSD

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - how is it GNU sed syntax? `-i` is available also on FreeBSD and OSX, which have a `grep` that doesn't understand `-Z` as `--null`. Anyway, good info.

Comment: @grebneke, it's `sed -i '' -e s/.../` in BSD `sed` (no optional options there)

Answer (score 15):

## Use `sed` with `find` instead of `grep`

First of all, I would employ `find` rather than `grep`, and this for three good reasons:

1. `find` allows for more precise file selection. For example, `grep -r string *.txt` will yield files only in the current directory; not those in subdirectories.
2. `find` comes with the powerful `-exec` option which eliminates the need for the whole `--null … |xargs 0` construct.
3. The `-readable` and `-writable` options of `find` will prevent wasting time on files that cannot be accessed.

## Capture test

That said, `grep` does lend itself for a first test to see what would be captured:

```
$ find . -exec grep term1 {} \;
```

or more specifically:

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.txt' -readable -writable -exec grep term1 {} \;
```

## Dry run

Now, proceed with a `sed` dry run.
The `sed` option `-n` is a synonym for `--quiet` and the `p` at the very end of the `sed` expression will print the current pattern space.

```
$ find . -exec sed -n 's/term1/term2/gp' {} \;
```

or more specifically:

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.txt' -readable -writable -exec sed -n 's/term1/term2/gp' {} \;
```

## Execution

If everything looks fine, issue the definitive command by replacing `sed` option `-n` by `-i` for "in place" and by removing the `p` at the end.

```
$ find . -exec sed -i 's/term1/term2/g' {} \;
```

or more specifically:

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.txt' -readable -writable -exec sed -i 's/term1/term2/g' {} \;
```

## More `find` examples

More `find` examples can be found [here](http://hamwaves.com/find/).